# Xamarin.Forms - ContentView - DisplayActionSheet

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have page. In the page I have items - each one is a `grid`. In the `grid` i have few `contentviews`. In one of them - i have button.

Now I want try to display to user `DisplayActionSheet`. - But Because it's a content view - I cant call it -

I also tried `App.Current.MainPage` - but its doent help me.

P.S - Also question - maybe you know way to do something like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h
In xamarin?

Thank you

Comment: You'll need a service or an event or a message to notify the owner page to show the action sheet

Comment: Can you give a link to example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *just* one way of doing it by using `MessagingCenter`.

In your ContentView you can going to **publish** a message when you want the containing page to perform a `DisplayActionSheet`. In the ContentView you can also **subscribe** to the result of the `DisplayActionSheet` if desired by having the `ContentPage` publish the result of the user's selection and whatever has subscribed to that message id (your `ContentView` maybe) can then react to it.

#### `ContentView`-based code:

```
var gridButton = new Button { Text = "This button is in a Content View" };
gridButton.Clicked += delegate
{
    var questions = new List<string> { "My ActionSheet Title", "Cancel", "Delete", "Share" };
    MessagingCenter.Send<object, List<string>>(this, "PhotoMessageQuestion", questions);
};

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "PhotoMessageAnswer", (sender, arg) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User choose: {0}", arg);
});
```

---

#### `ContentPage`-based code:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, List<string>>(this, "PhotoMessageQuestion", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    var photoAction = await DisplayActionSheet(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2], arg[3]);
    MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "PhotoMessageAnswer", photoAction);
});
```

#### Results in:

[image]

Comment: Wow - looks good way. I'll check it and update here about results. Thank you any way!!!!!

Comment: Ok - I just checked this way - and its work great. THANK YOU!
Topic can be closed )